# filepicker.io alternatives

Tags: javascript, file-upload, filepicker.io

Are there any filepicker.io alternatives which allows you tu upload the files to your own server?

We like to have some kind of integration with Dropbox, Google Drive and Office 365

Comment: What server environment are you using?

Comment: Rather than an alternative, you may be able to get filepicker.io to work for your needs. Once you get the filepicker.io URL you can download the contents to your server using a GET request or one of the server-side libraries

Comment: Yes that's also possible but because the files are for legal purposes we need to store them on our own server, preferably without Amazon s3 in between.